# How to delete a manually saved session

Tags: kubuntu, kde, session

I'm still a newbie to Linux and I'm using Kubuntu. I would like to know if there is a command to delete saved sessions that I manually saved.

I know it is possible by going to settings and using the *Start new session* in KDE, but I need a command to quickly delete that, because Kubuntu is restoring the session I saved about 3 weeks ago every time I log in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible graphical solution: A graphical sessions management tool may exist in KDE. [Session Management](https://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Startup_and_Shutdown)

Non-graphical backup solution: I believe you need to open up a Terminal and enter

`rm ~/.kde4/share/config/ksmserverrc` & `rm -r ~/.kde4/share/config/session/*` & `rm -r ~/.config/session/*`

These should clear all saved sessions, hopefully. [Research](http://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/477708-manually-saving-restoring-KDE-sessions)

Answer (score 4):

For ones who don't have the files from the answer of [@larouxn](https://askubuntu.com/a/508693/449016) in `~/.kde4/` nor in `~/.kde/`, try checking in `~/.config/` directory instead.

Answer (score 2):

For latest versions of KDE:

```bash
rm -r ~/.config/{session,ksmserverrc}
```