# How to disable Telegram auto startup in Kubuntu 16.10?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, startup, telegram

I am using a default Kubuntu 16.10, with KDE Plasma v5.7.5.

I installed Telegram Desktop using a downloadable installer from the official page.
The problem is it now loads up and opens on every startup. Aside from 
finding it aesthetically unpleasant, I think it's adding considerable 
overhead to the startup time.

*I've tried:*

- The client for Telegram itself has *very* limited options, none of which
  manages the startup behavior.
- Strangely, Telegram doesn't show up under `System Settings > Startup and 
  Shutdown > Automatically Started Applications` (unlike, for example, 
  Dropbox).
- Checking if I also installed Telegram with the terminal (possible cause of weird behavior), but I haven't.

*Possible solutions:*

- It might be one of the services under `System Settings > Startup and 
  Shutdown > Background Services`, with a non-obvious name.
- I might have to uninstall Telegram and find a version with a non-invasive startup policy, if it exists.
- Worst case, I'll have to use a startup script that looks for the Telegram process and kills it.

Ideally I want the Telegram service to boot up on startup, without the GUI spawning every time I log in.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem that you're experiencing albeit in a Xfce. Telegram starts at login and apparently it cannot be changed through the default startup/session settings.

The most probable cause for this is that your sessions cache is corrupted, and if that's the case then you'll have to manually clear it. In my case, this indeed was the problem and clearing the session cache fixed it.

Unfortunately unlike Xfce it seems that KDE does not provide an obvious way to do this. But perhaps it can be done with Session Management in Startup and Shutdown as is given here: https://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Startup_and_Shutdown. Starting with an empty session should work the same as clearing the cache. You can find further discussion about this here: [How to delete a manually saved session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508666/how-to-delete-a-manually-saved-session).

In Xfce this can be done by going into the Settings Manager > Session and Startup > Session tab > Clear saved sessions.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Hexman's answer is correct, but it is pretty hard to notice the required field, and the `kde.org`'s description is way too laconic.

Here's the entry field you're interested in:

System Settings → Workspace → Startup and Shutdown → Desktop Session → On Login → **Applications to be excluded from sessions:**

Tested on Xenial.

[image: screenshot Telegram disabled within Session]

Comment: I had the same problem not only with Telegram but also with some other software. I could not find those applications in "Applications to be excluded from sessions". What fixed the issue was just checking the `Start with an empty session` item (the third option in the picture).

Comment: Is that a space delimited list, or are their semicolons or commas between each program?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite old topic, but I faced it in Kubuntu 17.10 KDE Plasma 5.10.5

The solution which worked for me was to switch **System Settings → Workspace → Startup and Shutdown → Desktop Session → On Login → Start with an empty session**. Then quit Telegram and reboot.
After reboot **On Login** parameter may be switched back to **Restore previous session**. Telegram is no longer running on startup